# How to compute a smooth-degree isogeny given a generator point of its kernel?

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, isogeny

I need to compute an isogeny from $E: y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$, given a generator point for its kernel subgroup, using Python.
The point has smooth order.

I need both the parameters for the curve and polynomials for point mappings.

I have already read about Vélu's formulas, but it seems it will take a lot of time to compute each point in the subgroup, and more time to evaluate the curve parameters.

I know PARI and MAGMA provide an algorithm for that, but I need to understand the algorithm to write it on my own.

I am trying to use this for computing SIDH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity of Vélu's formulas scales linearly with the size of the kernel subgroup, so directly applying them to a point of huge order is not feasible for isogenies of "cryptographic" degree.

Instead, SIDH implementations *decompose* an isogeny of degree $\ell^n$ into $n$ isogenies of degree $\ell$. An easy way to do this is the following:
Suppose given a point $P\in E$ of order $\ell^n$, where $\ell$ is "small"; we wish to compute $E/\langle P\rangle$.
We decompose the isogeny $\varphi\colon E\to E/\langle P\rangle$ as:
$$
    E = E_0
    \xrightarrow{\psi_1} E_1
    \xrightarrow{\psi_2} E_2
    \xrightarrow{\psi_3} \dots
    \xrightarrow{\psi_{n-1}} E_{n-1}
    \xrightarrow{\psi_n} E_n = E/\langle P\rangle
    \text,
$$
where each $\psi_i$ has degree $\ell$.
A straightforward calculation shows that the kernels of the isogenies $\psi_i$ can be obtained by pushing $P$ through the previous isogenies $\psi_1\dots\psi_{i-1}$ and multiplying by an appropriate cofactor:
$$
    \operatorname{ker}\psi_i = \langle[\ell^{n-i}](\psi_{i-1}\circ\dots\circ\psi_1)(P)\rangle
    \text.
$$
Since $\lvert\operatorname{ker}\psi_i\rvert=\ell$ is small, computing each $\psi_i$ is efficient.
(Of course, this representation can also be used to efficiently evaluate $\varphi$ at a given point by simply passing the point through the chain of $\psi_i$s.)

Notice that it is this decomposition that gives the legitimate users of the system an advantage over attackers: It allows Alice and Bob to compute an isogeny in time logarithmic of the computational effort that an attacker needs to perform. In that sense, it is serves the same purpose as square-and-multiply (and its variants) for group-based Diffie-Hellman instantiations.

Finally, note that this straightforward strategy for computing $E/\langle P\rangle$ is not necessarily the most efficient possible: Depending on the relative costs of isogeny computations and point multiplications, there may be better strategies; see [the original SIDH paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506) (Section 4.2.2) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Use Velu formula with all the points of the subgroup. Sure it would take too long for a large subgroup, and this is why group order is considered like $2^m 3^n$. I think you understand it ok with the subgroup.

Comment: say, im using p=2^(372)3^(239) - 1
so the ord(R) is 2^(372) right? that means the kardinality of the subgroup will be 2^(372), isnt that too much point to evaluate?

Comment: Hello, have you read sections 1.3.4–1.3.7 of the SIKE spec? https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Post-Quantum-Cryptography/documents/round-1/submissions/SIKE.zip If that's not clear enough, I'd be happy to give more explanations.

Comment: @LucaDeFeo: yes actually i just read SIKE spec and there is some thing still bugging me.
I quite understand about the section 1.3.6 about computing $(l_A)^{e_A}$ 
degree isogeny by composing $l_A$ degree isogeny $e_A-1$ times, but i still dont understand section 1.3.7 about the strategy $(s_1,... s_{t-1})$ of size $t-1$ that you mention in the section.

Also what is the different between SIKE and SIDH? sorry to ask but i cant figure the difference between them

Comment: Section 1.3.7 describes an algorithm to compute the same results faster. You can disregard it if you're trying to understand the mathematics behind SIDH, but it is very important for implementers.

Comment: SIDH is an ephemeral key exchange protocol, like Diffie Helman. SIKE is a suite comprising a public key encryption protocol (à la El Gamal), and a Key encapsulation protocol (similar to El Gamal + AES). They are all based on the same primitive.

Comment: If you still have doubts, it's best to edit the question to make it clearer and more useful to others, possibly splitting it into several questions for better clarity. Do not hesitate to @-mention me in the comments, so I don't miss new the questions.

Comment: @LucaDeFeo : Ok sorry, this is the first time i'm using this forum and still dont know much about how to post questions properly. 
Since i have new question regarding to the old question, should i post a new question or edit this question?

Comment: You may start by reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question. Regarding your new question, you should first decide whether your original question has been answered. There is here a (very good) answer by @yyyyyyy, but, since you haven't accepted it, it is not clear whether you are satisfied by it. If you are, you should accept the answer, and eventually create new questions for other doubts you may have. If you aren't, you should make your question more precise (by editing, or by adding comments).